# Clearing a hyperlink column of it's value in a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: updatelistitems

In a SPD 2007 workflow, I was able to use the "Update List Item" action to clear the value in a hyperlink column that had a value by simply specifying the field in the  "Update list Item" action and entering nothing for its value.

[image: Update List Item]

In a SPD 2010 when I do the exact same thing, instead of getting cleared the hyperlink column's value becomes: http://

Does anyone know how I would actually clear a hyperlink column completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable of type string, leave it empty, then assign it to the link field.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It gives me the same result that I was originally seeing. Instead of being empty, the hyperlink field gets set to: http:// or <a href="http:// ">http:// </a>

Comment: Whoops, I was wrong! I'm not even sure my original problem was indeed a problem. Turns out I was running into updates to SPD 2010 WFs not showing up on the servers problem, discussed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a63a1894-6b1d-420a-95dd-b6c546eab34d/updates-made-to-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow-do-not-show-up-on-the-server?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious